# The regular points of a rational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\proj}{\mathbb{P}}$ Let $X\subseteq \proj^n$ be an irreducible projective variety over an algebraically closed field (of characteristic $0$). Let $\phi: X \dashrightarrow \proj^m$ be a rational map represented on some non-empty open subset by an $m$-tuple of homogeneous forms of the same degree $(F_0:\dots : F_m)$. Under what conditions on $F_0, \dots, F_m$ is the domain of $\phi$ precisely $\cup_{i=0}^m D(F_i)$?

This question is motivated by Shafarevich, Chapter 2, Section 1, Exercise 18(b):
[image]

in which I would like to show that $x$ singular $\Rightarrow F_i(x):=\partial F/\partial x_i (x)=0$ for all $i$ $\Rightarrow \phi$ not regular at $x$ (the last implication being what I am struggling with).